# Vim and PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

Tags: python, vim, coding-style

Could you recommend, how to configure Vim to stick to :

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

when editing python2/3 files, and only those (I'd like to leave configuration as it is for all other filetypes).

Answer (score 31):

## As 2020

Using [ale](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) plus installing a linter `pip3 install pylint` is asynchronous and therefore probably the better idea. It does not block when you save, syntastic will block. It also works for other languages (like syntastic). It is based on the Language Server Protocol.

---

## Old Answer (2014)

Using [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) plus installing `pip install flake8` gives you the best experience IMHO. `syntastic` is great, because it not only does pep8 checks for Python, but by installing other software it's really easy to add syntax checks and the like for other languages.

## Old Answer (2013)

`vim-flake8` is the better choice, I will try it :-)

## Oldest Answer (2012)

There's also a little script called 'pep8' - https://github.com/vim-scripts/pep8

I have it configured on 8:

```
let g:pep8_map='<leader>8'
```

I really like it. It works really good.

Comment: Syntastic + flake8 is really the way to go, and stupidly simple to set up.

Comment: pylint is still not working well with ale (use flake8), follow https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/issues/2522 for updates.

Answer (score 17):

There's [vim-flake8](https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8), which is most easily set up using [vim-pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) or [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle).

Comment: I like the simplicity of this over other solutiones (ALE, Ruff, Syntastic, etc.)

Answer (score 11):

The answers are focusing on checking the style after source code has been written but the question seems to be about making vim stick to the pep8 style during editing *itself*.

The main problem I've had with vim and pep8 is indentation, which can be fixed using this vim script:

EDIT3: Fix the terrible English...

EDIT2: Whoops, wrong script! Fixed.
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=974

EDIT1:

The script has been forked on github:

https://github.com/hynek/vim-python-pep8-indent/

Comment: Good catch! I've encountered problems with indentation and similar stuff during editing mostly. Of course - "after editing" periodical stylechecks can be run, but having it during edit it more comfortable.

Comment: With vim 7.4 (and probably earlier), a newer version of the file references in "EDIT2" is already included with vim by default.  If you simply include `if has("autocmd")
  filetype plugin indent on
endif` in your ~/.vimrc or /etc/vimrc, it automagically gets loaded on an out of the box vim.  (that's three separate lines, BTW, and it's probably already in the default vimrc on most current systems)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use the inclusive [klen/python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode#-python-mode-python-in-vim) plugin.

Where you can use `:PymodeLintAuto` for PEP8 errors and warnings with every time you save your code.

- https://github.com/klen/python-mode#-python-mode-python-in-vim

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [vimrc](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/Vim/vimrc) configuration file which I prefer to use. It takes care of all PEP8 configuration.