# Expand tabs to spaces in vim only in python files?

Tags: python, coding-style, vim

How do I have the tab key insert 4 spaces when I'm editing "*.py" files and not any other files?

Following a recommendation from [Vim and PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864543/vim-and-pep-8-style-guide-for-python-code), I installed vim-flake8 (and vim-pathogen). This gives warnings when PEP8 style guidelines are violated. This is great, but I would for tabs to be expanded automatically in the first place when editing python files. I would like to have tab key actually insert tabs when editing other types of files.

In other words, I want the following to apply when I'm editing python files and only python files:

```
set expandtab       " tabs are converted to spaces
set tabstop=4       " numbers of spaces of tab character
set shiftwidth=4    " numbers of spaces to (auto)indent
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
autocmd Filetype python setlocal expandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

Or even shorter:

```
au Filetype python setl et ts=4 sw=4
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question so quickly (stackoverflow is making me wait several more minutes until I can accept it)!