# PEP 8 compliant code in Vim

Tags: python, vim, pep8, flake8

Is there a good way to setup Vim to handle [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliance?

I've tried a couple vim plugins, pep8, and flake8.  These are good at identifying errors, but they don't "auto-correct" you as you type.  I don't want to worry about manually handling proper spacing.

In particular, the 79 character line limit.  I can set textwidth=79, but that doesn't intelligently identify where to break lines.  For example, this will incorrectly over/under indent the new line, causing pep8/flake8 to complain, and it will split in places that is syntactically incorrect (for example, on a %), and cause the code not to run.

Does anyone have a solution that works well for them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim and PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864543/vim-and-pep-8-style-guide-for-python-code)

Comment: I found something that appears to be working reasonably well: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3003.

Comment: This one also looks like it could work, though I haven't tried it yet: https://github.com/hynek/vim-python-pep8-indent/.  Thanks for the answers below, but I specifically wanted something that would do proper indentation while I typed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried vim-autopep8?

https://vim-autopep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

https://github.com/tell-k/vim-autopep8

It is not *as you type*, but I think is not that bad to press a command to fix formatting once in a while

Comment: Did it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I like python-mode. It does not auto correct, but does mark errors.  It combines features from pylint, rope, pydoc, pyflakes, pep8, and mccabe.

https://github.com/klen/python-mode